# JQuery Mobile checkbox not displaying correctly

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, checkbox

After assigning values from a HTML5 DB table. All values are displayed correctly but the checkbox, I'm assigning the value "true" or "false".

```
function loadDTValues(v1) {
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM CourseDataTable', [], function (tx, results) {
            $('#coursemenu').val(results.rows.item(v1).t_coursemenu).change();
            $('#checkbox1_2').val(results.rows.item(v1).t_checkbox1_2).selectmenu('refresh');
            $('#functionmenu').val(results.rows.item(v1).t_functionmenu).change();
            $('#startdate').val(results.rows.item(v1).t_startdate);
            $('#enddate').val(results.rows.item(v1).t_enddate);
            $('#courselocation').val(results.rows.item(v1).t_courselocation).change();
            $('#courseteacher').val(results.rows.item(v1).t_courseteacher).change();
            $('#comment').val(results.rows.item(v1).t_comment);
            $('#dt_id').val(results.rows.item(v1).t_id);
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For checkboxes you should set the checked property not val and then refresh the checkboxradio widget (not selectmenu):

```
$("#checkbox1_2").prop( "checked", true ).checkboxradio( "refresh" );
```

Comment: So I changed your code to $("#checkbox1_2").prop( "checked", results.rows.item(v1).t_checkbox1_2 ).checkboxradio( "refresh", true ); so the value would change from true  o false based on the table. It still does not work. It is now displays true even if the value is false.

Comment: This is my hack… adding a if else statement to test the value and then use your command. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: var v2 = results.rows.item(v1).t_checkbox1_2; if (v2 == "true") {
     $("#checkbox1_2").prop( "checked", true).checkboxradio( "refresh", true );
    }else{
     $("#checkbox1_2").prop( "checked", false).checkboxradio( "refresh", true );
    };